# What does the following sentence mean ? "Since when is ..."

Tags: spoken-english, formal-language, informal-language

I saw the following sentence and I cannot understand its exact meaning.

> Since when is W equal to PV ?

I do not understand the combination of "since + when".

Is it also formal or informal?

By the way W means work, P means pressure and V means volume. Basically, it is a mathematical formula.

Comment: Can you add what context this is in?

Comment: It's informal, expressing disbelief: "Since when did you have a Mustang?" The formula should involve the *change* in volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the answer by @Colin Fine is correct, it doesn't completely cover the usage.

Example

*John:  Bill, your grammar isn't good, I think you should study more.*

*Bill: Huh! Since when are **you** an expert on grammar? I get better marks than you do.*

Comment: Actually, that is more suitable for the context that I read, So I will accept this as a correct answer. Thanks @chasly

Answer (score 2):

It's a common informal way of saying "I don't believe that is correct".

On the surface it is saying "As far as I know, X is correct. How long has what you said been right?"

It is slightly combative, but less than saying directly "That's wrong".

Comment: There are other uses of "since when"/

Comment: I would say it is *more* insulting than saying ""You're wrong"

Comment: Maybe, @chasly-supportsMonica. Perhaps it depends on the social context